# Value between a range of values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, excel-2013, worksheet-function

Having this:

```
Class   Min    Max
Alfa    0      16.5
Beta    16.5   18.5
Charlie 18.5   25
Delta   25     30
```

And this:

```
Value X
35.52600894
26.27816853
29.53159178
29.84528548
26.77130341
25.07792506
19.2850645
42.77156244
29.11485934
29.5010482
19.30982162
```

I want a cell to have something like an IF statement (it's got a few more values in it, not this small, it has 8 class). An IF statement this long would probably not work (IF limit of 7) and is an ugly way of doing it. I was thinking of using `hlookup`, but I'm not sure if that's the best bet. 
I can also swap the columns within a table, so I could have "Min| Max| Class"
X values are in a column.

Basically: `=IF(X>=0 && X<16.5, Alpha, IF(X>=16.5 && X<18.5, Beta, IF(...`

Comment: With your data aligned left-to-right (you want to get the class from the first column) you'll have to use `Index` and `Match` functions, or create a separate table with these values where you put `Class` in the third column, then you can use `VLOOKUP`.

Comment: Edited the question, but:
pnutts: More class values, 8 rows. X values are in a column and 25 is Delta. 
David: I can swap the columns on a given table, no problem there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean VLOOKUP and would be much better way to go.

Make a Ranges sheet like this

```
Min    Class
0      Alfa
16.5   Beta
18.5   Charlie
25     Delta
30.5   Unidentified
```

In your detail sheet use formula "=VLOOKUP(A2,Ranges!A:B,2,TRUE)" [The True is important]

And you get

```
Value X Class
35.52600894 Unidentified
26.27816853 Delta
29.53159178 Delta
29.84528548 Delta
26.77130341 Delta
25.07792506 Delta
19.2850645  Charlie
42.77156244 Unidentified
29.11485934 Delta
29.5010482  Delta
19.30982162 Charlie
```

Comment: See if I got it right: Given a value, it looks up on the Min value if it is between the given min and the next. If True, returns the Class. That it?

Comment: Pretty close. The True says you want an approximate match. With False, the 16.5 would only match 16.5. With True it matches anything 16.5 or above that does not match a higher value. The 2 is what says that you want column 2, the Class (That's why I switched the columns in the ranges)

Answer (score 1):

With your Max range named `MaxVal` and your Class range named `Class`, please try:

```
    =IF(A2>30,"",INDEX(Class,MATCH(A2,MaxVal)))
```

(adjust references to suit).

[=MATCH()](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/match.php) here is using the `match_type` parameter of `1`: “The MATCH function will find the largest value that is less than or equal to value. You should be sure to sort your array in ascending order.

If the match_type parameter is omitted, the MATCH function assumes a match_type of 1.”

Any X value greater than `30` returns a blank (`""`) but text may be inserted to suit (eg `"Unidentified"` instead of `""`).

The formula could be simplified by removing the error trap, if a row were inserted immediately under the labels with `Alpha` under `Class` and `0` under `Max`. Also by removing the condition, in a similar way.

It is not necessary to specify both bounds of each range.

INDEX/MATCH was chosen rather than say VLOOKUP for reasons as given [here](http://www.excelhero.com/blog/2011/03/the-imposing-index.html).

PS For the Greek *alpha*bet α is usually Alpha.

*Edit re clarification*

The easiest fix for `25` is `Delta` rather than `Charlie` may be to deduct a small amount from each Max value, eg change `25` to =`25-1/1E100`.

Comment: I ended up using asantaballa's 'cause I'll have to explain how I got to get this to work and how does it work, and honestly his answer is easier in that respect, although I understand why Index + Match is faster and more efficient on large iterations. Thank you for your answer anyway =)